# regex to extract this string or use json decode

Tags: php, regex, string, curl, json

In PHP what would the regex be to extract "taken" from below, considering that it is dynamic and is always after status:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Sat, 09 Feb 2013 23:07:09 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: Noelios-Restlet-Engine/1.1.7
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 147
X-Cache: MISS from geonisis-2.eurodns.com
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from geonisis-2.eurodns.com:80
Via: 1.0 geonisis-2.eurodns.com (squid/3.1.10)
Connection: keep-alive

{"service":"availability","domain":"","timestamp":1360451229,"content":{"domainList":[{"status":"taken","name":""}]}}
```

The following shows that I should be using json decoded. How would one achieve this?

The above in generated using:

```
$process = curl_init($host);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/xml', $additionalHeaders));
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payloadName);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$return = curl_exec($process);
```

Comment: better to parse the JSON string, and then select from the object

Comment: Why not use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)?

Comment: You could remove the header from the response by setting `CURLOPT_HEADER` to 0 (false) instead of 1 (true).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the header from the response by changing:

```
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
```

And then decode the JSON string with:

```
$data = json_decode($curlResponse, true);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you discard headers from the response, you can use:

```
$json = '{"service":"availability","domain":"","timestamp":1360451229,
"content":{"domainList":[{"status":"taken","name":""}]}}';
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
echo $data['content']['domainList'][0]['status'];
```

Comment: Disable inclusion of header in the response: `curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);` and you will get only the JSON string

Answer (score 1):

Why care about the header? That's a JSON string, just decode it and you'll have an object that you can access easily

in php:

```
$jsonobj = json_decode('{"service":"availability","domain":"","timestamp":1360451229,    "content":{"domainList":[{"status":"taken","name":""}]}}');
```

in javascript:

```
var jsonobj = JSON.parse('{"service":"availability","domain":"","timestamp":1360451229,"content":{"domainList":[{"status":"taken","name":""}]}}');
```

Comment: remove the header from the curl response `curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);` and just parse the response like above

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = '
    HTTP/1.0 200 OK
    Date: Sat, 09 Feb 2013 23:07:09 GMT
    Accept-Ranges: bytes
    Server: Noelios-Restlet-Engine/1.1.7
    Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
    Content-Length: 147
    X-Cache: MISS from geonisis-2.eurodns.com
    X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from geonisis-2.eurodns.com:80
    Via: 1.0 geonisis-2.eurodns.com (squid/3.1.10)
    Connection: keep-alive

    {"service":"availability","domain":"","timestamp":1360451229,"content":{"domainList":[{"status":"taken","name":""}]}}';

$parts = explode("\n", $string);
$json = end($parts);
$data = json_decode($json);

$status = $data->content->domainList[0]->status; die;

echo $status;
```

---

*Edit (based on the question update):*

Remove the CURLOPT_HEADER line from your cURL request. This would simplify the response and make it easier to parse.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to work with headers, you have two options;

```
// first: regex
preg_match('~"status":"(.*?)"~i', $return, $match);
// print_r($match);
echo $match[1]; // taken

// second: json encode
$response = explode("\r\n\r\n", $return, 3);
// print_r($response);
$json_object = json_decode($response[2]);
$json_array  = json_decode($response[2], true); // toArray
// echo $json_object->content->domainList[0]->status;
echo $json_array['content']['domainList'][0]['status'];
```